# detect invalid byte in utf8

Tags: c#, stream

I'm implement a  text read that read from end to start,  I face two problems

1. the stream can only read forward
2. can not guarantee the first byte is a start of `char` if I get a 1kb buffer from the stream end.

I'm looking into the `Decoder` class and the `DecoderFallbackBuffer` , but I didn't find a way to detect the invalid bytes.

```
void Doo() {
     var b = new Span<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("你好啊，兄弟们哼哼哼"));
     var b3 = b[2..];
     WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b3));
     WriteLine(decoder.FallbackBuffer.Remaining);
     while (decoder.FallbackBuffer.Fallback(b3.ToArray(), 0))
     {
         var r = decoder.FallbackBuffer.Remaining;
         WriteLine(decoder.FallbackBuffer.Remaining);
         b3 = b3[1..]; // move forward
     }
     WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b3));
 }
```

```
 Doo()
�好啊，兄弟们哼哼哼
 0
 1
System.ArgumentException: Recursive fallback not allowed for bytes \xE5 \xA5 \xBD \xE5 \x95 \x8A \xEF \xBC \x8C \xE5 \x85 \x84 \xE5 \xBC \x9F \xE4 \xBB \xAC \xE5 \x93 .... (Parameter 'bytesUnknown')
  + System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.ThrowLastBytesRecursive(byte[])
  + System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallbackBuffer.Fallback(byte[], int)
  + Submission#7.Doo()
```

Is this possible in C# ?
What do I need to detect the first valid byte's position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that and second and subsequent bytes in a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence all start with `10` ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding)).

```
var b = new Span<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("你好啊，兄弟们哼哼哼"));
var b3 = b[2..];

while (b3.Length > 0 && (b3[0] & 0xC0) == 0x80)
{
    b3 = b3[1..];
}

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b3));
```

Alternatively you can use a decoder with a `DecoderReplacementFallback` to replace all invalid byte sequences with a replacement character, and then strip off the replacement character. `Encoding.UTF8` uses a replacement character by default.

If you want to get a string out, just:

```
var b = new Span<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("你好啊，兄弟们哼哼哼"));
var b3 = b[2..];

var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b3).TrimStart('\uFFFD');
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If you want to get the index of the first valid character without going via a string, I guess you could do something like (not particularly well-tested):

```cs
var b = new Span<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("你好啊，兄弟们哼哼哼"));
var b3 = b[2..];

var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
Span<char> chars = stackalloc char[1];
int pos = 0;
while (pos < b3.Length)
{
    decoder.Convert(b3[pos..], chars, false, out int bytesUsed, out int charsUsed, out bool completed);
    if (completed || (charsUsed > 0 && chars[0] != '\uFFFD'))
    {
        break;
    }
    pos += bytesUsed; 
}

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b3[pos..]));
```

Comment: the last one is I need,  but  sadly  the `\uFFFD` is not a constant value,  you can  replace it by  set the `Fallback` poroperty to other  `DecoderReplacementFallback` with other  character

Comment: @John Right, but it's set to `\uFFFD` by default. If you want to change that, you can create your own decoder and specify your own fallback character. But `\uFFFD` is the dedicated Unicode replacement character (and so won't be confused with anything else), so it's the most sensible choice

Comment: @cantib7   I'll ask it on runtime repo,   I'd perfer this capability is build in inside  the `Decoder` so it'll also work for other encoding

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/76163

Comment: This is only possible in UTF-8. In UTF-16 you can't tell if you're starting in the middle of a 2-byte character (although you can tell if you start in the middle of a surrogate pair). In UTF-32, you can't tell if you start somewhere in the middle of a 4-byte character. Almost all other encodings are single-byte, so the issue doesn't arise.